# advice on gambrel roof garage with 2nd floor apartment

Tags: hvac, insulation, garage, attic, ventilation

1st time home owner, plan to keep property long term so like to do things the best way possible for long term. Doing as much myself as possible.

Looking for advice on completing apartment above a garage space which is partially sheetrocked & textured.

– The nature of the gambrel roof along with the apartment being rectangle box, leaves a “side attic” area behind the side walls. 87” at top of this area and 3 feet wide at bottom. The subfloor has a two foot opening on the outside edge leading down into the garage below. Going to open up this side attic area in a few spots to utilize more space, near the headboard of the bed to have it inset, possibly where the toilet goes, & maybe 1 or two other spots. This will put the walls in these areas right against the side roof rafters, any suggestions on insulation ventilation there?

-Should I complete the subfloor all the way to the edge enclosing the garage below completely?

-The roof has ridge vent & gable vents on each end. It does provide a small soffit on each side at the very bottom, It is 1×6 board currently not vented. The top plate of the interior walls does provide a 1-2 inch gap for air flow up to the attic area. Thinking about adding baffle vents to ensure insulation does not block that area.  Also considering radiant barrier on roof joists leaving 2 inch gap between roof sheathing & foil

-The garage has four cinderblock size floor vents, ok to close these off?

-is encapsulating the entire thing a good or bad idea?

thank you for your time & any experience/advice shared

Comment: If you drive a Electric car then no problem, anything else's fumes could kill who ever is living there.

Comment: Not just fumes, but fire hazards from garage spaces. Please look into barrier requirements between garage and living spaces above. No openings through which flame can pass, Fire-rated drywall separation required, etc.

Comment: Electric cars can burn really, really well when things go wrong....

Comment: What sort of ground snow loads do you get where you live?

Comment: What is the spacing/span/depth of the floor joists of this space? (The root of my question is to find out if it was built in the first place to support living space.)